# What is causing these brown holes that go through my young cherry tree's leaves?

Tags: tree-care, cherries

What is making these holes in my cherry tree's leaves? And if it's a threat to the health of the plant, how can I stop these holes from forming?[image: brown holes in underside of cherry tree leaf]

Answer (score 1):

The holes and the missing part looks like attacks from a larvae. It could be damages made by beetles too.
It does not resembles attacks from snails.

Take a look a this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lepidoptera_that_feed_on_Prunus):

> Prunus species are used as food plants by the caterpillars of a number
> of Lepidoptera (butterflies and moths).

[Sweet cherries](https://www.rhs.org.uk/fruit/cherries/grow-your-own) are called P. avium

Use "mouse over" on the names in the list for photos (See e.g. Geometridae). Perhaps you can recognize one from your region.

To keep your tree healthy it is important that you in late summer/autumn remove all leaves and fruits from the ground.
Also be sure to attract insect eating birds.